# How to use Time Machine with File Vault

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine, filevault

I have a Mac with one user using File Vault.  I am enabling Time Machine. How do I make sure the File Vaulted directory gets backed up?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the tick mark next to it. Otherwise, please comment on what is missing. Thanks!

Comment: @daniel it did.  and i did (and upvoted). sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log out with the Time Machine disk attached. It will first recover disk space, then backup. This is the only method supported by Apple.

If you only want to encrypt some files, you can create encrypted disk images using `Disk Utility` and copy those files there, trashing and secure deleting the originals afterwards. The `Sparse Bundle` format is the technology underlying FileVault.

Comment: I've been suffering for years because of this. Once a week at least, I log off, so it backs up my ~.

Comment: How long do you have to log out for?  Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: You only have to log out while it backs up, the time varies depending on the amount of changes.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: It's just another step during logout, like recovering FileVault disk space. It displays a progress bar during logout just like with recovering disk space. Once it's done, you see the login screen, and if the screen lighting is dimmed because of the long idle time, it goes back to full.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: Added info you asked in your duplicate question to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## FileVault 1 in Snow Leopard

### Logging out

The method supported by Apple is as described in the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/199578/how-to-use-time-machine-with-file-vault/199596#199596).

In addition: if using a laptop you should use AC power, or prefer to backup while on battery power (the default to not backup while on battery power [probably began in Mac OS X 10.5.3](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/08/05/12/new_time_machine_option_in_10_5_3_boston_store_opens_thursday.html)).

### Without logging out

See answers to the Ask Different question:

- [How can I get Time Machine to back up the contents of a File Vault while logged in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3739/8546)

## FileVault 1 in Lion

### Logging out

No different from the routine for Snow Leopard.

### Without logging out

Work in progress, broader than FileVault 1:

- [How can Time Machine in Lion backup the volume content (not the bands) of a sparse bundle disk image?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20049/8546)